# Conditional formatting for a cell in a Table in my report

Tags: reportbuilder

I’m trying to use conditional formatting for a fill color in a table cell in a report. The statement I’m using is:

`IIF (GETDATE() >= (DATEADD(day, 25,  B6CONDIT.B1_CON_ISS_DD)) AND (GETDATE ()  <= (DATEADD(day, 30,  B6CONDIT.B1_CON_ISS_DD)), "Yellow", "White"))`

I'm getting an error when I try to apply it to my table that says:

"IIF (GETDATE() >= (DATEADD(day, 25,  B6CONDIT.B1_CON_ISS_DD)) AND (GETDATE ()  <= (DATEADD(day, 30,  B6CONDIT.B1_CON_ISS_DD)), "Yellow", "White")) is not valid color."

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
Phil R

I've made sure that my parentheses are matched and I know that Yellow and White are valid colors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your parentheses are correct? Try this:

```
=IIF(
(GETDATE() >= (DATEADD(day, 25,  B6CONDIT.B1_CON_ISS_DD))) AND
(GETDATE ()  <= (DATEADD(day, 30,  B6CONDIT.B1_CON_ISS_DD))), "Yellow", "White")
```